# How to periodically clear NSCache in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I'm struggling to think of a good solution here. So, in my app, I have a UITableView that loads user data, and each cell has a profile image UIImageView. So, every single time it's looping through the cells, it's individually downloading the profile pic for each user. For THIS reason, I started using NSCache to store the profile pics. This worked tremendously, and now the lag is gone.

However, what if someone changes their profile pic? The profile pics are uploaded in backend one per user. I use User ID to reference these profile pics. If someone changes their profile pic, it will just load the image I have in the cache, and not their new image. So, I want to have the entire cache on the IOS device cleared like once every 3 hours, or so. That will cure everything. How do you clear the entire NSCache at intervals?

TL;DR:
How would I clear the whole NSCache for an app at time intervals? (example: have the app cache cleared every 3 hours)

Comment: I think change your backend image id is far more efficent than clear cache in your app, if you clear then the other user data would be cleared also, and not really much user will use the app for 3 hours straight

Comment: @Tj3n I'm only caching the profile pictures! All the other information is downloaded real time

Comment: I know you only caching the profile pictures and get new data everytime, thats why i said change image id is better, since you wont need to clear the cache and still know the new image id to download if it change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the app delegate methods and implement a check every time the user enters foreground of the app. You could keep a variable that holds the last time the user opened the app and if the current time is 3 hours past then, clear the cache.

As stated in the comments, most users will not have 3 hour sessions.

On a side note: Most users may understand images not updating immediately, For instance, I know twitter takes awhile to update. In my app, I leave the cache alone and re-download all images any time the app is completely quit. If you compress the images before putting them on the server this won't hurt data usage to bad.

Comment: Best answer by far. I am actually compressing the images, so yeah, that's not a problem actually. I am actually now curious about your "side note". So, what method would I put this in exactly? didEnterBackground or willEnterForeground?

Comment: @JohnLeonardo So for the side note, I just let them die as the app dies. Luckily, that just happens because my NSCache (And I suspect yours) is just a variable, which means when the app is force quit i.e The user double clicks home button and swipes up, the variable goes back to its initial declaration the next time you launch the app.

Comment: @JohnLeonardo If you wanted to specific on when you delete the cache, i.e every 3 hours, That is when I would use the app delegate. And I would probably use applicationWillEnterForeground method      If my answer works for you, please select is as the accepted answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Dude, thanks so much. Haha, yeah my NSCache is a variable as well, and I never knew that it wasn't persistent (silly me), so it's probably fine to leave it as is. Selecting this answer!